# 1.9 One Page Checkout Checkout as Guest button to continue not working

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, onepage-checkout

I noticed some strange behavior with Magento 1.9 using the One Page Checkout Page. When checking out and selecting the "Checkout as Guest" then clicking the "Continue" button doesn't display the next steps such as the billing, shipping, shipping method forms. The "Continue" button is unresponsive and I see the JQuery errors in Firebug.

I built the template of the RWD theme and I upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9.

What I did notice is that it is trying to load the JQuery-1.10.2.min.js file which is not at the location and it is trying to load off the base template (skin/frontend/base/default/js/lib) when I checked the files weren't there.

[image: Errors before adding missing Jquery files]

So I added them to the location but when I added them the entire checkout components disappears and it starts to behave strange where the attributes no longer show in the drop downs and I can't "add to the cart" from the product pages.

This is the errors I get when adding the missing JQuery-1.10.2.min.js file
[image: errors in products pages when adding JQuery-1.10.2.min.js. Attibutes do not show in dropdown and can't add items to cart as the button is unresponsive]

I am not sure if something went wrong in the upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9 or there is a conflict with JQuery but NoConflict is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by adding the $j = jQuery.noConflict(); to the app.js file that Magento is using. The app.js is being used by all of the pages particularly it appears to be for the dropdown and to populate the attributes.

Once I added the above code to the app.js file and uploaded the missing jquery library as well as updated the Page.xml file within my theme to reflect the files everything worked.

I gather that during my upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9 (I used Magento Connect) various files were not updated and some files were missed and therefore broke my store.

So be cautious when upgrading your stores that there could be a possibility that some things are not going to go well.

Comment: @shireen gave the the same answer 2 days before this, and you literally ignored his answer, answered yourself, and picked it as the correct answer? at least give the guy an upvote. :/

Answer (score 2):

Are you using jquery in your checkout page?If its not use there then call it only on those pages where it is required.
Remember whenever using jquery please define jquery no conflict in head.phtml like this  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();  inside the script tags.

Good Luck!:)